# Como puedo añadir texto a un .bat

Tags: cmd, batch

quiero crear un archivo .bat en donde pueda crear un archivo de texto y definir su contenido desde el .bat y que no me lo solicite en CMD, es decir, al crear el .bat y ejecutarlo quiero que me cree un archivo de texto y que dentro de el ya esté definido un texto el cual escribiría en el código y no en CMD. Adjunto imagen de uno de mis intentos fallidos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con `echo Texto de prueba> Texto.txt`.

Comment: @Sal Existe alguna manera de crear saltos de línea?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma, defines el texto y defines el archivo en el cual se agregará el texto:

```
echo Texto de prueba > Texto.txt
```

Puedes usar también `@echo off` para que no se realice la impresión de los comandos simplemente cree el archivo con el texto:

```
@echo off
echo Texto de prueba > Texto.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

mira para hacer uno que se abra al siguiente tienes que entrar en notas y escribir esto. supongamos que "x" es el nombre de tu documento.

"

do

Set shell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")

Shell.Run("x.vbs")

loop

"

después dale a "guardar como" y pon el nombre con la terminación ".vbs".
ejemplo (x.vbs)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una **lista de echo's** para hacerlo (**es bastante repetitivo con un archivo largo** pero no hay otra alternativa mas que hacerlo con otro lenguaje)

```
@echo off
(
    echo Hola, texto de prueba.
    echo.
    echo Hola, otro texto de prueba.
    echo Hola, otra vez un texto de prueba.
) > archivo.extension
```

El resultado de ese script sería un nuevo archivo que se llama **archivo.extension** y que contendría las siguientes líneas:

```
Hola, texto de prueba.
(línea vacía)
Hola, otro texto de prueba.
Hola, otra vez un texto de prueba.
(línea vacía)
```

La línea vacía del final se puede quitar con una instrucción especial, pero muy complicada de entender y no te quiero sobrecargar de cosas.